# Load a formatted binary file and assign information to structure c++

Tags: c++, stream

I've finally figured out how to write some specifically formatted information to a binary file, but now my problem is reading it back and building it back the way it originally was.

Here is my function to write the data:

```
void save_disk(disk aDisk)
{
    ofstream myfile("disk01", ios::out | ios::binary);
    int32_t entries;
    entries = (int32_t) aDisk.current_file.size();
    char buffer[10];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d",entries);

    myfile.write(buffer, sizeof(int32_t));

    std::for_each(aDisk.current_file.begin(), aDisk.current_file.end(), [&] (const file_node& aFile)
    {
        myfile.write(aFile.name, MAX_FILE_NAME);
        myfile.write(aFile.data, BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME);
    });

}
```

and my structure that it originally was created with and what I want to load it back into is composed as follows.

```
struct file_node
{
    char  name[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    char  data[BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME];

    file_node(){};
};

struct disk
{
    vector<file_node> current_file;
};
```

I don't really know how to read it back in so that it is arranged the same way, but here is my pathetic attempt anyway (I just tried to reverse what I did for saving):

```
void load_disk(disk aDisk)
{
    ifstream myFile("disk01", ios::in | ios::binary);
    char buffer[10];

    myFile.read(buffer, sizeof(int32_t));

    std::for_each(aDisk.current_file.begin(), aDisk.current_file.end(), [&] (file_node& aFile)
    {
        myFile.read(aFile.name, MAX_FILE_NAME);
        myFile.read(aFile.data, BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME);
    });

}
```

**^^ This is absolutely wrong. ^^**

I understand the basic operations of the ifstream, but really all I know how to do with it is read in a file of text, anything more complicated than that I'm kind of lost.

Any suggestions on how I can read this in?

Comment: why do you write aFile on whole of the file, not better just try a one write of aFile and read one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. You need to write **and** read the length as binary.

This part of your length-write is wrong:

```
char buffer[10];
sprintf(buffer, "%d",entries);
myfile.write(buffer, sizeof(int32_t));
```

It only writes the first four bytes of whatever the length is, but the length is character data from a `sprintf()` call. You need to write this as a binary-value of `entries` (the integer):

```
// writing your entry count.
uint32_t entries = (uint32_t)aDisk.current_file.size();
entries = htonl(entries);
myfile.write((char*)&entries, sizeof(entries));
```

Then on the read:

```
// reading the entry count
uint32_t entries = 0;
myFile.read((char*)&entries, sizeof(entries));
entries = ntohl(entries);

// Use this to resize your vector; for_each has places to stuff data now.
aDisk.current_file.resize(entries);
std::for_each(aDisk.current_file.begin(), aDisk.current_file.end(), [&] (file_node& aFile)
{
    myFile.read(aFile.name, MAX_FILE_NAME);
    myFile.read(aFile.data, BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME);
});
```

Or something like that.

Note 1: this does NO error checking nor does it account for portability for potentially different endian-ness on different host machines (a big-endian machine writing the file, a little endian machine reading it). Thats probably ok for your needs, but you should at least be aware of it.

Note 2: Pass your input disk parameter to `load_disk()` by **reference**:

```
void load_disk(disk& aDisk)
```

**EDIT** Cleaning `file_node` content on construction

```
struct file_node
{
    char  name[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    char  data[BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME];

    file_node()
    { 
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
    }
};
```

If you are using a compliant C++11 compiler:

```
struct file_node
{
    char  name[MAX_FILE_NAME];
    char  data[BLOCK_SIZE - MAX_FILE_NAME];

    file_node() : name(), data() {}
};
```

Comment: It looks like I can read the file with this, as in I'm getting information, but it looks like it is still binary info that is filling up my vectors... any idea why it wouldn't be interpreting it?

Comment: @JasonM. When you say "read the file with this" do you mean a previously existing file *prior* to the change for *writing* posted at the top of this answer?? I ask because clearly that will not work. The older written format didn't have a 32-bit signed integer written as the length in binary-form. Also, you can zero-out your buffers on `file_node`'s constructor to ensure the only non-zero byte-data written is the content you updated with each.

Comment: I just realized I was making a silly mistake by recalling a variable I hadn't set yet by mistake, but I'm messing with the char array, trying to figure out a good way to test it.

Comment: @JasonM. No worries. I'll update the code to clean our your arrays on construction. There are even simpler ways to do this than the above code, but this should get you running.

Comment: Looks like it works pretty good! Aside from the problems you have already mentioned in portability and what not, this works great for my specific purpose. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JasonM. Good to hear. You can make the size-write portable by using uint32_t and translating the value using htonl() on the write, ntohl() on the read. Look both of those up in your docs before embarking on that little tryst. I've updated the source to include where/how they should be put, but look them up anyway and see why they're needed.